# Tricky confusion with the definition of a weak solution for the linear parabolic equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes, parabolic-pde

Let us consider the linear parabolic PDE:
\begin{equation}
\partial_t u - \Delta u=f \text{ and }u(0)=u_0
\end{equation}
where $u_0 \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and $f \in L^2_t([0,T], L^2_x(\mathbb{R}))$.

Then, the definition of a weak solution is, according to Evans PDE, that
\begin{equation}
\langle u(t), v \rangle_{L^2_x}+ \langle \nabla u(t), \nabla v \rangle_{L^2_x}=\langle \nabla f(t), \nabla v \rangle_{L^2_x}
\end{equation}
for each $v \in H^1(\mathbb{R})$ and a.e. $0 \leq t \leq T$ as well as $u(0)=g$

Here, I am extremely confused about the a.e. $0 \leq t \leq T$ condition. That is,

Does the set of $t \in [0,T]$ that satisfies the above equation "depend on" each $v$??

This seems quite tricky and no reference seems to state the exact conditions..

Could anyone please help me?

Comment: No, because $T > 0$ is fixed. Another way to read the definition is: For every $v\in H^1(\mathbb{R})$, the equation is satisfied for $t$ a.e. in $[0, T]$.

Comment: @CheeHan I don't understand. $T$ affects my question?

Comment: Are you asking if $0\le t\le T$ changes for every $v$?

Comment: @CheeHan yes, exactly. That really confuses me..

Comment: @CheeHan, more precisely, the set of $t$ in the fixed internal $[0,T]$ depends on each $v$?